# How can I share SQL connection object through classes?

Tags: java, sql, javafx, singleton

I'm currently building a program with SQL in JavaFX.

I am calling `DbConnect()` in my main window and it all works fine.
The Issue I am having right now is to get this database connection in other classes (Another window/scene). Right now I am calling the DB connection function in all other scene's also which will cause issue's later on because it always opens a new database connection. So my question here is how can I share the database connection in all my classes.

Only want to open it once in main class and then inherit it to the other classes

Here is my Database connection function:

```
    public Connection DbConnect() {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbPath, user, pass);
        statm = con.createStatement();
        SetupSystem();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
```

From the first window

```
//  Initilizing all the database connections
public void DbConnect() {
    con.DbConnect();
    disconnectMenuItem.setVisible(true);
    connectMenuItem.setVisible(false);

}
```

From the second Window (don't want to open new connection here) want to inherit connection from the first window

```
            public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        db.DbConnect();
}
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: Multithreading is the way. Implement the multiple threads for the same session connection you want like `public Class Conn extends Thread {dbconnect_methods...} public class main_class{psvm(){ for (int i=1 to 10) {Thread t1=new Conn();}  }}`

Comment: Why don't you simply use a singleton pattern?

Comment: Guess I need to learn multithreading now.

@EhsanKhodarahmi what is singleton pattern?

Comment: I guess you need to make database connection class as [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) that can share one instance through your classes:

```
public final class Singleton {

private static volatile Connection con = null;

private Singleton() {}

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (con== null) {
       try {
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbPath, user, pass);
     statm = con.createStatement();
    SetupSystem();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }

    return con;
 }
```

}

Now,you can access to your database connection from the other classes like this :

```
 public class ClassOne {
   Singleton.getInstance();
  }

  public class ClassTwo {

   Singleton.getInstance();
  }
```